# Write JSON data to HTML5 table

Tags: javascript, php, json, html

I've got the following snippet of code:

```
function getData(){
        $.get('http://mywebsite.net/getFile.php', function(data) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        }
```

That returns the following JSON data:

```
Object {0: "11", 1: "MobileAppBackUp150715", 2: "rob@gmail.com", FileID: "11", FileName: "MobileAppBackUp150715", FileEmail: "rob@gmail.com"}
```

I've two issues:

First of all my JSON data is incorrect, there should be more than one object returned. Here is how I'm creating my JSON data:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT FileID, FileName, FileEmail FROM tblfiles WHERE FileEmail = '".$email."'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row['FileEmail'] == $email) {
    echo json_encode($row);    
}
```

In the table `tblfiles` there are 2 rows of data I know for definite.

My second issue is I'm not sure how to go about writing my JSON results into a html table.

EDIT: UPDATE:

using the following php script I've managed to output the 2 rows that I know exist in my table:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT FileID, FileName, FileEmail FROM tblfiles WHERE FileEmail = '".$email."'");

$row = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id = $r["FileID"];
        $row[$id] = $r;
    }
}
echo json_encode($row);
```

That produces the following:

```
{"11":{"FileID":"11","FileName":"MobileAppBackUp150715","FileEmail":"rob@gmail.com"},"14":{"FileID":"14","FileName":"MyFile","FileEmail":"rob@gmail.com"}}
```

Now I need to use JS to get into a table in a HTML page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, to do everything in a single command in your callback function, you could do

```
$('#target').html('<table>'+$.map(result,function(d){return '<tr><td>'+$.map(d,function(e){return e;}).join('</td><td>')+'</td></tr>'}).join('\n')+'</table>');
```

Where `#target` is the id of a div where you want the table to be and `result` is the object you got from your `$.get()` call. I have not done the headings yet but that should be easy for you to fix.

```js
var result={"11":{"FileID":"11","FileName":"MobileAppBackUp150715","FileEmail":"rob@gmail.com"},"14":{"FileID":"14","FileName":"MyFile","FileEmail":"rob@gmail.com"}};

$('#target').html('<table>'+$.map(result,function(d){return '<tr><td>'+$.map(d,function(e){return e;}).join('</td><td>')+'</td></tr>'}).join('\n')+'</table>');
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Where are are you referencing my JSON data in order to create your answer? - Actually sorry sill me! I see it

Comment: `result` is the object that you got inside your callback function. I get everything from there ...

Comment: It looks ok to me. Also check out my updated answer. It now also contains a working code snippet. Was quite hard work to write it on my 5 year old iPod.  ;-)

Comment: Haha I can imagine it would be difficult alright! I've added your snippet however no results are displaying. Here is the full html page http://pastebucket.com/88171

Comment: Okay I will. I'll let you know how I get on. Thanks

Comment: Try using `$.getJSON()` instead of `$.get()` as this will parse the result string into an object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use jquery to answer you. You can easily add jquery to your project.

```
var $row = "<tr><td>" + result[0] + "</td><td>" + result[1] + "</td></tr>";
var $table = $("table"); //selects your table
$table.append(row);
```

That's a way to do it. It is simple but probably not the best. I can recommend looking into some plugin such as knockout.js if you need to populate a lot of html based on json

hope it helps!

Comment: Hey Nest, thanks for your answer however now I have more than one JSON object (as per my update above). Any ideas?

Comment: follow the method twice. Once for each row

Comment: This was a valid solution, at least you could give me vote up as useful

Comment: Apologies. I did actually forget.

Answer (score 0):

On the back of the accepted answer above I'd like to share the code that is working for me.

There is no need to use `JSON.parse()` as using `getJSON()` function already returns the JSON data as on object.

```
 <script>
    $.getJSON('http://safe.net/getFile.php', function(json) {

        var tr;
        for(var i in json)
        {
            tr = $('<tr>');
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].FileName + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].FileID + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].FileEmail + "</td>");
            $('table').append(tr);
            console.log(json[i].FileName);
        }

        //console.log(json);    

        });
</script>
```

Thanks to cars10 above for the help.